# Constructor expecting shared pointer to the instance being created

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have encountered a class that requires a `std::weak_ptr` as a constructor argument. The problem is that the weak pointer must be pointing to a `shared_ptr` that owns the instance being created. I cannot figure out how to pass said pointer, since the `shared_ptr` itself is only constructed or assigned to after the class has been constructed.

```
struct SomeClass
{
    SomeClass(std::weak_ptr<SomeClass> ptrToThis){...}
    ...
};
```

I've tried the following for passing the `weak_ptr` to the constructor, but it fails (I presume this happens because the original `shared_ptr` no longer uses the same sentry object internally after getting assigned to)

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> shared;
    std::weak_ptr<SomeClass> weak;
    weak = shared;
    shared = std::make_shared<SomeClass>(weak);
    //this prints "1" (true)
    std::cout << weak.expired();
    return 0;
}
```

How could this be corrected? Since I can modify the original class, should I modify it somehow, for example adding a separate function for setting the value of the `weak_ptr` after construction?

Comment: Why would somebody pass a weak_ptr to itself? What are you trying to do? You cannot mass this in anyway into a ctor as it is created in the ctor

Comment: Are you trying to recreate [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)?

Comment: I'm quite new to C++11, and somehow I was unaware of `std::enable_shared_from_this`. At a quick glance that seems like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off using [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), which was designed for situations like this.

To use it, derive your class from it. It will store a `std::weak_ptr` which will be initialised to point to the object the first time a `std::shared_ptr` pointing to that object is created:

```
struct SomeClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SomeClass>
{
  //...
};
```

If you need to make sure a `std::shared_ptr` to your class always exists, you can make all of its constructors private (or protected, as applicable) and give it a public static creation function returning a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
struct SomeClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<SomeClass>
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> create()
    { return std::make_shared<SomeClass>(); }

private:
    SomeClass()
    {}
};
```